# EntityFramework Model-First metadata for breezejs

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, asp.net-web-api-odata

Breeze.js library requires metadata of the entity context. Web API OData has a default ODataConventionModelBuilder for this operation, but doesn't work for Breeze, since it lacks foreign key information. Thus, Breeze offers a special package called "EdmBuilder" to generate this information. However, it only works with Code-First approach. If there is an existing edmx file, it gives the following exception;

> Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created
>   using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be
>   obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing
>   DbCompiledModel.

In short, if there is an existing edmx file in the project, how it can be published as metadata information to breezejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since generating this information will done in runtime, it had to be about reading the loaded resource. While I was trying to figure it out, I found this link;
https://gist.github.com/dariusclay/8673940

The only problem was that regex pattern didn't work for my connection string. But after fixing that, it generated the information what breeze was looking for.

In the end, I've merged both breeze's Code-First and this Model-First methods in the following class (surely it can be improved). Hope it can be useful to someone else.

**UPDATE**

Now it also determines whether DBContext is Code-First or Model-First.

```
using Microsoft.Data.Edm.Csdl;
using Microsoft.Data.Edm.Validation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;

namespace Microsoft.Data.Edm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// DbContext extension that builds an "Entity Data Model" (EDM) from a <see cref="DbContext"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// We need the EDM both to define the Web API OData route and as a
    /// source of metadata for the Breeze client. 
    /// <p>
    /// The Web API OData literature recommends the
    /// <see cref="System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder"/>.
    /// That component is suffient for route definition but fails as a source of 
    /// metadata for Breeze because (as of this writing) it neglects to include the
    /// foreign key definitions Breeze requires to maintain navigation properties
    /// of client-side JavaScript entities.
    /// </p><p>
    /// This EDM Builder ask the EF DbContext to supply the metadata which 
    /// satisfy both route definition and Breeze.
    /// </p><p>
    /// This class can be downloaded and installed as a nuget package:
    /// http://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.EdmBuilder/
    /// </p>
    /// </remarks>
    public static class EdmBuilder
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Builds an Entity Data Model (EDM) from a <see cref="DbContext"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the source <see cref="DbContext"/></typeparam>
        /// <returns>An XML <see cref="IEdmModel"/>.</returns>
        /// <example>
        /// <![CDATA[
        /// /* In the WebApiConfig.cs */
        /// config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
        ///     routeName: "odata", 
        ///     routePrefix: "odata", 
        ///     model: EdmBuilder.GetEdmModel<DbContext>(), 
        ///     batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer)
        ///     );
        /// ]]>
        /// </example>
        public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel<T>() where T : DbContext, new()
        {
            return GetEdmModel<T>(new T());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extension method builds an Entity Data Model (EDM) from an
        /// existing <see cref="DbContext"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the source <see cref="DbContext"/></typeparam>
        /// <param name="dbContext">Concrete <see cref="DbContext"/> to use for EDM generation.</param>
        /// <returns>An XML <see cref="IEdmModel"/>.</returns>
        /// <example>
        /// /* In the WebApiConfig.cs */
        /// using (var context = new TodoListContext())
        /// {
        ///   config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
        ///       routeName: "odata", 
        ///       routePrefix: "odata", 
        ///       model: context.GetEdmModel(), 
        ///       batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer)
        ///       );
        /// }
        /// </example>
        public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel<T>(this T dbContext) where T : DbContext, new()
        {
            dbContext = dbContext ?? new T();

            // Get internal context
            var internalContext = dbContext.GetType().GetProperty(INTERNALCONTEXT, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(dbContext);

            // Is code first model?
            var isCodeFirst = internalContext.GetType().GetProperty(CODEFIRSTMODEL).GetValue(internalContext) != null;

            // Return the result based on the dbcontext type
            return isCodeFirst
                ? GetCodeFirstEdm<T>(dbContext)
                : GetModelFirstEdm<T>(dbContext);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// [OBSOLETE] Builds an Entity Data Model (EDM) from an existing <see cref="DbContext"/> 
        /// created using Code-First. Use <see cref="GetCodeFirstEdm"/> instead.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This method delegates directly to <see cref="GetCodeFirstEdm"/> whose
        /// name better describes its purpose and specificity.
        /// Deprecated for backward compatibility.
        /// </remarks>
        [Obsolete("This method is obsolete. Use GetEdmModel instead")]
        public static IEdmModel GetEdm<T>(this T dbContext) where T : DbContext, new()
        {
            return GetEdmModel<T>(dbContext);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// [OBSOLETE] Builds an Entity Data Model (EDM) from a <see cref="DbContext"/> created using Code-First.
        /// Use <see cref="GetModelFirstEdm"/> for a Model-First DbContext.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the source <see cref="DbContext"/></typeparam>
        /// <returns>An XML <see cref="IEdmModel"/>.</returns>
        /// <example>
        /// <![CDATA[
        /// /* In the WebApiConfig.cs */
        /// config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
        ///     routeName: "odata", 
        ///     routePrefix: "odata", 
        ///     model: EdmBuilder.GetCodeFirstEdm<CodeFirstDbContext>(), 
        ///     batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer)
        ///     );
        /// ]]>
        /// </example>
        [Obsolete("This method is obsolete. Use GetEdmModel instead")]
        public static IEdmModel GetCodeFirstEdm<T>() where T : DbContext, new()
        {
            return GetCodeFirstEdm(new T());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// [OBSOLETE] Extension method builds an Entity Data Model (EDM) from an
        /// existing <see cref="DbContext"/> created using Code-First.
        /// Use <see cref="GetModelFirstEdm"/> for a Model-First DbContext.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the source <see cref="DbContext"/></typeparam>
        /// <param name="dbContext">Concrete <see cref="DbContext"/> to use for EDM generation.</param>
        /// <returns>An XML <see cref="IEdmModel"/>.</returns>
        /// <example>
        /// /* In the WebApiConfig.cs */
        /// using (var context = new TodoListContext())
        /// {
        ///   config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
        ///       routeName: "odata", 
        ///       routePrefix: "odata", 
        ///       model: context.GetCodeFirstEdm(), 
        ///       batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer)
        ///       );
        /// }
        /// </example>
        [Obsolete("This method is obsolete. Use GetEdmModel instead")]
        public static IEdmModel GetCodeFirstEdm<T>(this T dbContext) where T : DbContext, new()
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
                {
                    dbContext = dbContext ?? new T();
                    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(dbContext, writer);
                }
                stream.Position = 0;
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
                {
                    return EdmxReader.Parse(reader);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// [OBSOLETE] Builds an Entity Data Model (EDM) from a <see cref="DbContext"/> created using Model-First.
        /// Use <see cref="GetCodeFirstEdm"/> for a Code-First DbContext.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the source <see cref="DbContext"/></typeparam>
        /// <returns>An XML <see cref="IEdmModel"/>.</returns>
        /// <example>
        /// <![CDATA[
        /// /* In the WebApiConfig.cs */
        /// config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
        ///     routeName: "odata", 
        ///     routePrefix: "odata", 
        ///     model: EdmBuilder.GetModelFirstEdm<ModelFirstDbContext>(), 
        ///     batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer)
        ///     );
        /// ]]>
        /// </example>
        [Obsolete("This method is obsolete. Use GetEdmModel instead")]
        public static IEdmModel GetModelFirstEdm<T>() where T : DbContext, new()
        {
            return GetModelFirstEdm(new T());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// [OBSOLETE] Extension method builds an Entity Data Model (EDM) from a <see cref="DbContext"/> created using Model-First. 
        /// Use <see cref="GetCodeFirstEdm"/> for a Code-First DbContext.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the source <see cref="DbContext"/></typeparam>
        /// <param name="dbContext">Concrete <see cref="DbContext"/> to use for EDM generation.</param>
        /// <returns>An XML <see cref="IEdmModel"/>.</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Inspiration and code for this method came from the following gist
        /// which reates the metadata from an Edmx file:
        /// https://gist.github.com/dariusclay/8673940
        /// </remarks>
        /// <example>
        /// /* In the WebApiConfig.cs */
        /// using (var context = new TodoListContext())
        /// {
        ///   config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
        ///       routeName: "odata", 
        ///       routePrefix: "odata", 
        ///       model: context.GetModelFirstEdm(), 
        ///       batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer)
        ///       );
        /// }
        /// </example> 
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage( "Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202:Do not dispose objects multiple times" )]
        [Obsolete("This method is obsolete. Use GetEdmModel instead")]
        public static IEdmModel GetModelFirstEdm<T>(this T dbContext) where T : DbContext, new()
        {
            dbContext = dbContext ?? new T();
            using (var csdlStream = GetCsdlResourceStream(dbContext))
            {
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(csdlStream))
                {
                    IEdmModel model;
                    IEnumerable<EdmError> errors;
                    if (!CsdlReader.TryParse(new[] { reader }, out model, out errors))
                    {
                        foreach (var e in errors)
                            Debug.Fail(e.ErrorCode.ToString("F"), e.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                    return model;
                }
            }
        }

        static Stream GetCsdlResourceStream(IObjectContextAdapter context)
        {
            // Get connection string builder
            var connectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(context.ObjectContext.Connection.ConnectionString);

            // Get the regex match from metadata property of the builder
            var match = Regex.Match(connectionStringBuilder.Metadata, METADATACSDLPATTERN);

            // Get the resource name
            var resourceName = match.Groups[0].Value;

            // Get context assembly
            var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(context.GetType());

            // Return the csdl resource
            return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
        }

        // Pattern to find conceptual model name in connecting string metadata
        const string METADATACSDLPATTERN = "((\\w+\\.)+csdl)";

        // Property name in DbContext class
        const string INTERNALCONTEXT = "InternalContext";

        // Property name in InternalContext class
        const string CODEFIRSTMODEL = "CodeFirstModel";
    }
}
```

Comment: **This looks VERY PROMISING. May I include it in an update to the breeze labs version so that everyone finds it?** Of course I will thank you explicitly. P.S.: for backward compat I'd likely alias `GetCodeFirstEdm` with a deprecated `GetEdm`.

Comment: @Ward Of course, that would be great. About GetEdm method, in an ideal case, we should be able understand DbContext type (whether it's Code-First or Model-First). In that case, GetEdm method could stay and internally it could call either GetCodeFirstEdm or GetModelFirstEdm. Since you're talking about adding it breeze, I will try to investigate this. If I can find a way, I will update my answer and let you know?

Comment: That would be amazing if we could tell whether a `DbContext` was build code first or db first. I had moment of reluctance when I saw how many more using statements were required. But they all seem to be in assemblies you would reference anyway.

Comment: I have committed the update (w/ slight modifications), credited you, and updated the nuget package to v.1.0.3. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @Ward Thanks, I saw the new version. And I was working on understanding the context type. Since I couldn't find any documentation on this, I've simply compared both context types. There is property called CodeFirstModel; in Code-First type, that has a value and in Model-First it's null. The new method (GetEdmModel) is calling one of the inner methods based on this result. Currently it looks good, should I update the answer, or send it to you directly?

Comment: @Ward I've updated the answer. Although they're used internally, I've made old methods obsolete. You may want to check comments & remarks.

Comment: Thx, I'll update the lab and its nuget. I'll revert to one method and make the others private. It's only been two days so I don't think I'll worry about breaking anyone.

Comment: Done. Nuget v.1.0.4. Now we're back to one method ... `GetEdm` ... the original name, extended to work code- or model-first. I've de-listed v.1.0.3. I've verified with a code-first model. Please confirm that the model-first version works. p.s.: GetEdmModel is redundant as the 'M' in "EDM" is "Model" :-)

Comment: Yep, saw it, looks very clean now. And tested it with Model-First, it works. Good job sir! :) By the way, I've posted another minor update about breeze to its UserVoice. In case you wonder; [breeze.js createError function can't handle datajs errors](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5688201-breeze-js-createerror-function-can-t-handle-datajs)

Comment: @Ward Could you update the doc http://www.breezejs.com/samples/breeze-web-api-odata

Comment: @Ward Also both nuget & github links end with coma character and don't work

Comment: Patrick it is updated for next release (roughly a week away). Meanwhile you can update the nuget package yourself.

Comment: Serkan thanks for finding that; I believe i have fixed those links.

Comment: Sorry to hijack this question does anyone have a way to set the entityset on db generated edms set up so? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852292/how-to-add-entityset-when-using-breeze-edmbuilder