# Entity Framework Inheritance in breezejs and ASP.NET Web Api OData

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, asp.net-web-api-odata

I'm using breezejs with WebApi OData according to [this sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/breeze-web-api-odata). As stated in this article I cannot use ODataConventionModelBuilder because of the missing foreign key information. Suppose I have an entity named 'Car' which is derived from an entity named 'Vehicle'. With ODataConventionModelBuilder I can define a model such as this:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Vehicle>("Vehicles");
builder.EntitySet<Car>("Cars");
```

I can do the query like :

- /odata/Vehicles --> returns all the vehicles.
- /odata/Cars --> returns
  just the cars.

But with Breeze EdmBuilder class I can only use the '/odata/Vehicles' query. The '/odata/Cars' would result in a '404 not found' error.

It seems that when using 'ODataConventionModelBuilder', the 'Cars' entity set is defined in the metadata but when using the breeze EdmBuilder, it is not. I can confirm this behavior when sending request to the metadata end point('odata/$metadata'). This happens for both code first and model first approaches stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711496/entityframework-model-first-metadata-for-breezejs).

In short, how do I use inheritance when using EdmBuilder class in breeze and Web Api OData.

**UPDATED**

here is the metadata when using 'ODataConventionModelBuilder':

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
 <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
  <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="EFTest.Models">
   <EntityType Name="Vehicle">
    <Key>
     <PropertyRef Name="VehicleId"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="VehicleId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
   </EntityType>
   <EntityType Name="Car" BaseType="EFTest.Models.Vehicle">
    <Property Name="Capacity" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
   </EntityType>
  </Schema>
  <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="Default">
   <EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
    <EntitySet Name="Vehicles" EntityType="EFTest.Models.Vehicle"/>
    <EntitySet Name="Cars" EntityType="EFTest.Models.Car"/>
   </EntityContainer>
  </Schema>
 </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

here is metadata when using breeze EdmBuilder class:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
 <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0">
  <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="TestDBModel">
   <EntityType Name="Car" BaseType="TestDBModel.Vehicle">
    <Property Name="Capacity" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
   </EntityType>
   <EntityType Name="Vehicle">
    <Key>
     <PropertyRef Name="VehicleId"/>
    </Key>
    <Property xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" Name="VehicleId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" p6:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"/>
    <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true"/>
   </EntityType>
   <EntityContainer xmlns:p5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" Name="TestDBEntities" p5:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
    <EntitySet Name="Vehicles" EntityType="TestDBModel.Vehicle"/>
   </EntityContainer>
  </Schema>
 </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

here is the conceptual model section in the edmx file:

```
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="TestDBModel" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
    <EntityType Name="Car" BaseType="TestDBModel.Vehicle">
      <Property Name="Capacity" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityType Name="Vehicle">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="VehicleId" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="VehicleId" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Type="Int32" />
      <Property Name="Name" Type="String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityContainer Name="TestDBEntities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
      <EntitySet Name="Vehicles" EntityType="Self.Vehicle" />
    </EntityContainer>
  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
```

Comment: How is `Car` defined in the metadata? Would you please update your question with short snippets of the metadata for both the `Car` and `Vehicle` classes? Ultimately, if necessary, you can repair the damage with client-side coded metadata. But it would be nice to generate the right metadata on the server if we can.

Comment: @Ward: updated to include metadata for a sample model.

Answer (score 0):

What stands out for me is that the `Cars` "EntitySet" is missing from the EDMX conceptual model and, consequently, from the metadata generated by EdmBuilder. OTOH, you included `Cars` when you called `ODataConventionModelBuilder`.

You aren't really talking about the same "model".

I think (hope) you will get the desired outcome if you add the `Cars` "EntitySet" to the `DbContext`.

Comment: This sample is a model first EF context, so I guess this is by design. Because the derived type (Car) is shown on the edmx designer but it is not included as an EntitySet. I also checked it with a code first dbcontext. Including the 'Cars' as an EntitySet has no effect.

Comment: That just doesn't make sense. I take it that this is a tiny sample that we could easily load and understand. If so, would you put it somewhere that we can download and try? We need real code. Thanks.